# Problem about Convergence with probability one

Tags: probability

Suppose that ${X_n}$ are independent random variables and $E[X_n]$=0

Show that if $\sum_{n} Var(X_n)< \infty$ , then $\sum_{n} X_n $ converges with probability one.

How to prove this? Kolmogorov's inequality??

Comment: [Kolmogorov's two-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_two-series_theorem), if you want a hammer. Which is actually (a generalization of/equivalent to) your problem, and is, indeed, proven from Kolmogorov's inequality.

Comment: If you are familiar with martingale theory, you can apply a well-known convergence result for $L^2$-martingales.